# What's the correct way to write the general location of someone in the USA?

Tags: american-english, toponyms, international

I'd like to write where someone is from, on a website with an international context. The objective is to balance style, brevity and correctness. I only need country-level resolution, so if someone is from Berlin, I plan on writing *Germany*, whereas if they're from Sydney, I plan on writing *Australia*.

I suspect that the USA should be an exception here, as I often heard people from the States feel very much associated with their state (I heard a lot more *Chicago, Illinois* than, say, *Sydney, New South Wales*).

Does this sound like a reasonable assumption? How should I write the state/country pair in this case? *Illinois, United States*? *United States, Illinois*? Something else altogether?

**Edit:** another small tidbit, the lion's share of the target audience is in the teenager/young adult age range.

Comment: I can't speak for all 300 million of us, but, if the rest of the site is broken down at a national level, I see no reason to make an exception for those in the U.S.

Comment: You can do it by country (just USA), by state (but not for me), or maybe region: West Coast, East Coast Southwest, Bible Belt, Southeast, Midwest, Northeast, Alaska, Hawaii. J.R. has a point, though: There's no need to coddle provincial Americans unless one of 'em makes you an offer that you cannot refuse.

Comment: One does not write “Chicago, United States”; one writes “Chicago, Illinois”.

Comment: It is unclear what you want and what your constraints are and what is allowed (please edit your question). If you just care about country, the US is no exception, just say US. If you only know the state, then it is state first, then US. If you know the city it depends on how well known the city is, but the order would be city, state, US, or city, US (the latter for better known cities). But if this is self-described, it's not so much 'very much associated with their state' (Americans don't have the multiple allegiance dilemmas as in the EU), but you just say 'city, state, US'.

Comment: Why would it be an exception? Australia is divided by States, why differentiate the USA in this way? You're being inconsistent. You ideally need to define what it is you want to do and then perhaps formulate the correct way of doing it.

Comment: @spiceyokooko The problem is that City, Country is too ambiguous in the United States.  Many, many, many city names are repeated many times over. For example, there is a Springfield in every state in the Union. Thus City, USA tells you nothing in the general case.

Comment: Do not write "United States, Illinois" ... the other one is better, "Illinois, United States".

Comment: [This is what happens](http://www.680winr.com/cc-common/news/sections/newsarticle.html?feed=104668&article=10658349) when you don’t give enough detail.  And Merry Christmas.

Comment: @tchrist Perhaps I misunderstood what the OP was asking for (quite likely) but he seemed to be resolving locations down to Country level. Eg, Sidney becomes Australia, why would Springfield become Springfield, Illinois, USA instead of simply USA?

Comment: @spiceyokooko I agree that it is unclear. I no longer know what he is looking for, for sure.

Comment: Not sure why this is off topic, but I apologise if I made a mess. Anyway, I'll refer to the US only as 'USA' (no state). Thank you (everyone) for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the US we usually write *Berkeley, CA*, which is the name of the city followed by state.  That said, if you were treating people on a country level, simply writing *the US* or USA would suffice.

Comment: I'll clarify: I definitely want country and I'm *thinking* if states should be included. Maybe never, maybe just for the US, maybe for any place that has states (hrmf, probably not). Anyway, thanks for the answer, I'll wait a bit to see if more answers crop up.

Comment: @YanivAknin If you do not include the state, you will not know what particular city of that name which they are in, because city names repeat in different states.  Consider Portland or Springfield.

Comment: I'll further clarify: At this time, I can't add the city, period. It will be either country or country+state, but city is out of the question for now.

Comment: @Yaniv: Something else you might want to consider: if you decide to open it up to country+state, you open up a can of worms from a design perspective. (One can live in the United States without living in one of the 50 states).

Comment: @J.R. Like Washington, DC or San Juan, PR or Charlotte Amalie, VI.

Comment: I'll go with USA (no state). Thank you for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 1):

The customary format would be to include city name and two-letter state abbreviation (e.g. *Seattle, WA, USA*). Showing the full state name acceptable, but not necessary.

Only including the state (e.g. *Washington, USA*) can be ambiguous and vastly imprecise (California and Texas are larger than most countries). Some publications (The Economist magazine) use this, but it seems highbrow, unusual and weird to a teenage audience. It would look wrong next to city-state pairs from other countries (e.g. *Berlin, Germany*).

Only listing the city is ambiguous, as city names [repeat often](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_most_common_U.S._place_names) in the USA (there are 28 Springfields).

Comment: I’ve certainly known teenagers who were highbrow, unusual, and weird, and sometimes more than one of those at the same time. I cannot possibly imagine who this would “look weird” to teenagers.

Comment: @tchrist Teenagers tend to be a remarkably conformist bunch, even (or perhaps especially) in their non-conformity ("rebel" against society, but still a follower within a subculture).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using "country-level resolution" for other countries, doing the same for the US is reasonable and consistent. As I understand it, you wouldn't say someone is from Schleswig-Holstein, Germany, or Manitoba, Canada, so there's no reason to refer to Illinois, United States. The USA is a very mobile country, so identifying someone with a state is problematic. It's not unusual for someone to have grown up in Connecticut, gone to college in Massachusetts, and worked in Maryland. Would you cite them by place of birth, place where they've spent most of their time, place of current residence, or something else? That can of worms is better left unopened.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that there are several towns and cities in the US for which there is another town or city of the same name in another state.

There are also a very large number of towns and cities in the US for which there is another, often better known, town or city with the same name somewhere else (mainly, but not solely, in Europe).

This doesn't only apply to the United States (e.g. as well as the various places called San Jose and/or San José in the US, there are dozens around the world), it is common enough there that a general habit of giving the state along with the city or town is common.

In the use you are making of it though, country would probably suffice unless you've a good reason to be more precise.