# Word order of locations

Tags: word-order, toponyms, phrase-order

Is there a rule in the English language that governs the order of location specificity?

Once my English lecturer stated that in English locations are written from the smallest level up to the highest.
This would make these correct:

> Magenta street, Rome, Italy

> Institute of Biosciences, Life Sciences Centre, Vilnius University

And not these (or any other permutation):

> Italy, Rome, Magenta street

> Vilnius University, Life Sciences Centre, Institute of Biosciences

I have looked at several links, but there are no explicitly stated sources or any references to rules of the language.
These are the following:

- [Wikipedia - Address - Address format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address#Address_format) - *... addresses are written in order from most specific to general, i.e. finest to coarsest information ...*
- [Engilsh Stack Exchange - What's the correct way to write the general location of someone in the USA?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95563/whats-the-correct-way-to-write-the-general-location-of-someone-in-the-usa) - city, then state, not the other way around
- [Quora - Why do we write the name of a city and then the name of the country when we're writing a location?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-write-the-name-of-a-city-and-then-the-name-of-the-country-when-were-writing-a-location) - says that it is more comfortable for the post office to read in this order <sup>[why?]</sup>

But why finest to coarsest, and not coarsest to finest?
If it is a rule, I would like to see some links or references, so I could cite it while proofreading texts.

Comment: They are not rules of _language_, but conventions used by the postal services of different countries. As far as I know, addresses on letters in the British Isles have always been written in the order (house, street, town, county). We might refer in conversation to 'the Oxbridge University Department of Mathematics', but if you were addressing a letter to them you would write the department's name first.

Comment: Any nation's postal service will tell you how to address letters, but I guess you're looking for some other information, not how to address an envelope? If you're using a style guide for your proofreading then it should provide a clue on specific circumstances such as "city, state". For more on the why question (there are really multiple questions here) see https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/36066/which-cultures-are-big-endian

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with saying "I lived in Rome, on Magenta Street." You don't usually say "Magenta Street, Roma, Italy" unless you're giving an address, and for an address, you write it the way the postal service likes it.

Comment: You're not finding them because they don't exist. You're falling into the overgeneralization trap -- thinking that language works by a set of very broad, mathematical rules, and so one rule fits a zillion different situations.

Comment: Even in writing an address you don't use a strict smaller-to-bigger order: apartment/flat/room numbers often go after building numbers (UK: "10/2 Main St" or "10B Main St", US: "10 Main St #2"), and zip or postal codes go later than their status as subdivision of a city or state would suggest.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. From this thread I assume the best answer to this question is that it's not a rule, but conventions used by the postal services, which generally do not apply outside of addressing mail. Would it make sense to answer this question in such a fashion?